# Flutter random slowdowns

Tags: flutter, performance-testing

Recently I've built a (production) app with flutter. As the last phase I dived into profiling my app's performance, as I noticed occasional slowdowns (fps would drop to 30-ish for a few seconds to only then pick up again back to be snappy). After some digging and stripping out features to check my assertions first, I got all the way back to an app as simple as a list only displaying 100 containers with a color in them (nothing else really), and even when my app is this 'simple', I still get these slowdowns. An app cant really go simpler than that (most apps nowadays are lists), so I was wondering if anyone else has this issue too. Its kind of annoying because it looks really bad when the app slows down, and judging by my research this seemingly is inside the flutter engine itself and not something I can control.

Here is what would be the app, just put this inside main.dart and see for yourself:

```
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'my app',
      home: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            color: [
              Colors.red,
              Colors.orange,
              Colors.yellow,
              Colors.orange
            ][index % 4],
            height: 200,
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(height: 30),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Be aware this occurs occasionally only, just go ahead and scroll a bit while looking at the performance monitor where you can see frame times. There should be occasional single high bars, and every now and then (say once every two times of scrolling through the list) there will be a few seconds of long frame times (indexed as 'Jank (slow frame)' by the profiler from flutter / vscode).

[image: here's how it looks when everything is as normal (snappy)]
[image: here's how it looks when theres a slowdown period (many jank frames in succession)]
[image: here's one of the jank frames analyzed. It seems like the time is spent in the rasterizer, despite the widgets shown just being extremely simple colored containers]

I'm running:

- Flutter: 2.5.3
- Dart: 2.14.4.
- Physical test device: iPhone 12 Pro
- profile mode

My launch settings (vscode)

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Flutter",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "flutterMode": "profile",
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**TL;DR**
I'm having an 'as simple as possible' flutter project which just shows a long list (with cell reuse as it's a ListView.builder), and despite the simplicity, there are frequent lag spikes and framedrops (long 'raster' times). Flutter doctor shows nothing special

**Actual question**
Do other people have this issue as well? Does anyone have any idea where to look to find the real cause of this jank?

Comment: Just in case, I assume you are running the app in profile mode on your device (as opposed to debug mode)? In debug mode some functionality is handled differently, causing it to be janky when it wouldn't be in a real scenario (I know for sure this is something that happens in Android, I'm not 100% sure about iOS)

Comment: Thats correct, I'll update the post with my launch.json (vscode)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code on my own device (Xiaomi Mi A2, Android 10), and was unable to get any jank frames in the DevTools (even when scrolling really quickly).

Since the phone is quite cheap, I have experienced some janky animations before, but no such thing to speak of in this case.

Looking online, I do come across a few similar issues, one of which also discusses that this may be occuring because the listview doesn't know the size of elements beforehand: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52207

A way to improve the performance seems to be to use a SliverList (which the standard ListView uses under the hood too) with a fixed extent: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFixedExtentList-class.html

Of course, this only works if all of your list children are of the same fixed size (which is the case for your example, but probably not for your actual application).

Adapting your code, you would use something like the following:

```dart
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'my app',
      home: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverFixedExtentList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: [
                        Colors.red,
                        Colors.orange,
                        Colors.yellow,
                        Colors.orange
                      ][index % 4],
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }, childCount: 100),
              itemExtent: 230),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can try if this improves the situation for you on your device

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes, unfortunately my app needs dynamically sized cells, so using the SliverList is not an option. I did however test it in a freshly generated flutter app to see the difference from using ListView.builder, and unfortunately the behaviour stays the same. I see a single long bar (in between perfectly low frame times) every now and then (about every 5 seconds of scrolling), and occasionally, but this can take quite some time (like sometimes 2 minutes of scrolling) a bunch of slow frames. I'm suspecting it could also be iOS simply 'managing/distributing' cpu resources..